# How could I get value from SelectHTML?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am trying to get a value from a  dropdown list. A language type is assigned to the value in the list. An error is displayed during the download:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

in this line code:
`lang: langForm.elements.lang.value`

```html
<main>
    <form id="langForm">
    <section class="language">
    <label id="atr3" >Language: </label>
        <select id="langs" class="pure-u-1 pure-control-group"></select>
    </section>
    </form>

    <div id="info"></div>
    <div class="quote">
        <center><h1 id="atr1">Welcome to the Employee Reporting System website!</h1></center>
        <h2 id="atr2">Fill employee name </h2>
    </div>
    <form id="form" class="pure-form" style="width:50%; margin-left: 70px; margin-top: 180px">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="pure-input-rounded" placeholder="name" />
    <button id="btn" class="pure button pure-button-primary">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div id="returnMsg"></div>
</div>

<script>
        const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

        const CODE_TO_EMOJI = {
       'pl':'PL',
       'en':'EN',
       'de':'DE',
       'it':'IT',
       'fr':'FR',}

        fetch ('http://localhost:8080/api/langs')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(langArr => {
                const checkboxes = langArr.map (lang => `
                <option name="lang" value="${lang.id}" >${CODE_TO_EMOJI[lang.code]}</option>
                `);
                document.getElementById('langs').innerHTML = checkboxes;
            });

        const form = document.getElementById('form');
        const langForm = document.getElementById('langForm');
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formObj = {
        name: form.elements.name.value,
        lang: langForm.elements.lang.value
        };
        fetch (`${API_URL}?${new URLSearchParams(formObj)}`)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then((text) => {
                div.innerHTML = `
                <h1>${text}</h1>
                `;
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
```

I have tried very different configurations when get values and it still doesn't work.
Although the above retrieval of the "name" value from  works without a problem

Comment: You want to get the name and the value of the selected item or all the items ?

Comment: Why are you using the decades-obsoleted `<center>` element?

Comment: `<h2 id="atr2">Fill employee name </h2>` <-- This is an inappropriate use of `<h2>`. That text isn't a heading, it's an instruction.

Comment: You should avoid using the legacy input-names-as-`form`-object-properties part of the DOM (because it's easy to get `name=""` and `id=""` confused, as well as it really not handling the valid case of multiple inputs with the same `name=""`. Just use `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is that `langForm.elements.lang.value` _should be_ `langForm.elements.langs.value` but only after you add `name="langs"` to the `<select id="langs">`  - which is why you should just use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Thx for your help -> everything is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```js
const
  CODE_TO_EMOJI = {'pl':'PL','en':'EN','de':'DE','it':'IT','fr':'FR'}
, langForm      = document.forms['lang-form']
  ;
Object
.entries(CODE_TO_EMOJI)
.forEach( ([k,v]) =>
  langForm.langs.add( new Option(v,k)))
  ;
langForm.langs.onchange = () =>
  {
  console.log( langForm.langs.value )
  setTimeout( console.clear, 1000)
  }
```

```css
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<form name="lang-form">
  <label>Language: </label>
  <select name="langs" ></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to get the values of all the options in the dropdown list, you need to loop over all the options like this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('langs');
for(let i = 0 ; i < select.options.length;i++){
    console.log(select.options[i].value);
}
```

but if you want to get only the value of the selected item, you can easily use this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('langs');
var name = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```